# Force My jquery to run on any newly added dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have the following scripts, which contains two selectors:-

`$(document).ready(function () {
     if ($("#ChoiceName2").prop("checked")) {`

&

`$("#ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2").each(function () {
     $(this).change(function () {`

The selectors will not fire on any newly added Dom elements, usually i use the `.on` to force my jquery to run on any newly added elements as follow:-

```
$("body").on('click', '#DCSort', function () {
```

but not sure how i can add the `.on` to mt first script ?

Comment: Question is not clear to me. What is problem? Please rephrase your question.

Comment: Is the ampersand supposed to represent arbitrary code?

Comment: my original script should fire when the #ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2" are changed. but if i am returning a new DOM element which contains (#ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2") the script will not fire if these newly added (#ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2") DOM elements were chnaged

Comment: If you pass the selector as the second parameter in the `on` function it will.  It checks to see if what was clicked matches the selector you passed in.  In other words the click event is placed on the `body` (using your reference) then it bubbles up checking each element to see if it matches the selector you passed in.

Comment: #ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2 both represents ID, why you have .each() for that? it's going to return you only one element always. So .each() not required at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `#ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2` as selector, `$.each` is not required. As it's going to return you only one element always as it's an ID.

```
     $('body').on("change", "#ChoiceTag2, #ChoiceName2", function () {
```

This will do the trick for the newly added elements

Answer (score 2):

The best way to accomplish what you are trying to do is by using a CSS class that has no style definition, but will allow you to bind a delegate to events involving that class.

That way the delegate acts on the class, regardless of when it is added to the DOM.

Like this:

```
 <button class='DCSort'>Some Button</button>

 $('body').on('click', '.DCSort', function () {
 }
```